# Ignore numbers in a string

Tags: java, string

Example:

```
    String t;
    String j ="j2se";
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the search key:");
    t=sc.next();
    if (j.contains(t))
    {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
    else System.out.println("no");
```

If the user enters 'j2', 'se' or 'j2s' as an input the output is 'yes'. If the input is 'jse' the output is 'no'.

Is there a method to ignore the number stored in string search like ignoring upper or lower case letters?

Comment: not in-built, create copy of your string, and remove from it all characters which you dont need

Comment: only numbers? what if a user inputs "j@" or "j$y" is it ok ?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov sorry only numbers.. but still, I cn know more you can still help me

Comment: @clem is your task to remove numbers, or to preserve only letters?

Answer (score 5):

Why you don't juste create a copy of this string with no numeric inside ?
And after juste compare this new string with your array ?

Like :

```
String stringWithoutNumber = j.replaceAll("\\d+","");

stringWithoutNumber.contains(t);
```

Many of programs have a function called sanitize which clean the url or string before the comparaison.

Hope it's help

-- EDIT --

You don't need to put the `+` in `\\d+` because the method replaceAll replace all the digit. But it's more efficient because it makes less replacement.

Comment: @TheLostMind, I'm late ^^

Comment: Its never too late .. :)

Comment: @ThomasLeduc thanks! it works.. please can you explain me how this woks ? thanks

Comment: @clem It replaces all numbers in the string to the empty string. `replaceAll` gets a regular expression `\\d` which means any number, and replaces it to "".

Comment: Sure, I'm french, but I will try ^^
"\\d" is a regualar expression (also called regexp). d is a special character to say "digit".
So with this regexp the method replaceAll, contained in String object, will search all the digit ([0-9]) and replace them one by one to "".
So for example : 
"j2se".replaceAll("\\d", "") => "jse"
And "jse".contains("jse") is true.

Comment: @ThomasLeduc - I think its better to use `\\d+` (works for `java23se` ):P

Comment: You should mark the question as answered if you don't have questions anymore.

Answer (score 4):

use `replaceAll("\\d+","")` on the String and then compare.
This removes all the numbers from your String. Now you could use this new String and compare.
or use :

```
\\W+ // replaces everything apart from characters .
```